# NPM nullish coalescing not working aka Unexpected token?

Tags: node.js, npm, syntax-error, null-coalescing-operator

I have a nodejs API server and am using the nullish coalescing opperater.

That worked great for me so far, however since today I am getting the error message

```
      newsletter: req.body.newsletter ?? false
                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
```

I thought maybe there is an issue with some code before that so I replaced it with the oldfashioned

```
newsletter: req.body.newsletter ? req.body.newsletter : false
```

Which worked and the error message moved on to the next instance of the use of `??`

I am kind of lost what is happening here, I didn't really change anything and the error seems to only happen on my dev machine as the production environment still works fine.

I already tried updating node / npm and reinstalled my node_modules without any luck.